# Cannot login to my website

Tags: users, uri

I've logged out my drupal 7.22 website and have no login/admin block. It's hosted locally.

I've tried the following URL queries, with no desirable results. The page remains the same and I cannot locate any block I can use to log in-

- `localhost/drupal/user/logout` (Prints Access Denied on Title bar)
- `localhost/drupal/user/login` (Prints User Account on Title bar)
- `localhost/drupal/?q=user` (Prints User Account on Title bar)
- `localhost/drupal/?q=user/login` (Prints User Account on Title bar)

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered a solution to this problem. I removed all *.tpl.php files from the theme templates directory and placed only html.tpl.php back. localhost/drupal/?q=user Now brings up the login block.

The default admin black bar on top would not return this way however. To bring it back I had to follow [this instruction](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80473/what-variable-is-responsible-for-the-default-admin-bar-on-top-of-every-default-d).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you do not have .htaccess file in you website directory. Place it over there any check :)

Comment: .htaccess exists. And now I've even replaced it with the one that comes with drupal.

Still nothing.

Comment: localhost/drupal?q=user most probably wrong but try this url

Comment: If user account is getting print what are you getting in the html part ?with above URL

Comment: The HTML shows the usual site, as a viewer would see it. No login block or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you accidentally removed the login block, or otherwise broke the functionality.

Open up modules/system/system.module, and put the following code right after

```
global $user;
$user->uid = 1;
```

Then reload any page on the site and you'll be logged in as the main admin user. Then remove the above code, and (now that you're logged in) fix what missing login block.

Note that anyone who loads a page of your site while that code is in place will be automatically logged in as the main administrator!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the apache Rewrite module is activated too !! This fixed it for me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers! I would advise you to provide more details to your answer such as how this affects the issue. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer