# What variable is responsible for the default admin bar on top of every default Drupal theme?

Tags: users, theming

This is basically my html.tpl.php -

```
</head>
<body>
<?php print $page; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to add to make that horizontal admin bar appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stored in `$page_bottom`...you should also output `$page_top` to make sure you have a complete page:

```
</head>
<body>
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```